# Cant post to other form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my _layout page, because the searchbar in the navbar:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <div class="navbar-text">Zoeken</div>
        <input type="text" id="SearchText" name="SearchText" class="form-control" />
        <button id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

and this in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(string SearchText)
    {
        ProductDbContext pdb = new ProductDbContext();
        return RedirectToAction("Search", pdb.Search(SearchText));
    }

    public ActionResult Search(List<Product> producten)
    {
        return View(producten);
    }
```

but the code always enters this ActionResult on submit:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Please someone explain to me what I am doing wrong with submitting.
I am not able to solve this on my own somehow even tho it looks very simple to me.

Comment: Do you have nested forms?

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the button to input type and give it a try. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Input type of buttons can only be reset|submit|button. edit: didnt work

Comment: In your case, replace button tag with this <input id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search"> and you should be fine. The button do not do submit on its own that's why you are hitting the index method itself.

Comment: This is wrong, and makes no difference whatsoever - `<input type="submit" />` and `<button type="submit">` are identical

Comment: You are right and i do not oppose that.They are identical and used interchangeably. And this is not wrong its a workaround (considering the browser preferences). Button is recommended since we can embed css pseudo code to it. Both create a kvp in request but in her case there is no code flaw whatsoever.

Comment: @MelsvanEs can you please paste the whole section on your _layouts page so that we can see what's wrong with that.